# How to integrate Google maps in my Android App

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps

I am working on Android Application, in which there is a requirement of displaying map. I am working for 3 days to integrate but not getting any positive result.

I followed this tutorial [`Google Maps Android API v2`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/). But when i run the my app. its simply giving exception as

```
IOException processing: 26
java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)
at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.processDataRequest(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1117)
at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:994)
at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)
```

Here is My code:

Activity:

```
public class DisplayMap extends  MapActivity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mapView);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView 
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="AIzaSyA1MXQ1Hc4-VhOOfItFHA1WCsGFUGcJ-BQ"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.rakhi577.maptest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.rakhi577.maptest.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.rakhi577.maptest.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>


    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.rakhi577.maptest.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyA1MXQ1Hc4-VhOOfItFHA1WCsGFUGcJ-BQ"/>


</manifest>
```

I created the map using debug.keystore. Can any one help me please...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14195573/513413

Answer (score 0):

Use Google maps v2

```
      <fragment  
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_below="@id/rg_views"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
      />
```

and A.java

Googlemap gm;

gm = ((SupportMapFragment)(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))).getMap();

A complete tutorial can be seen in this. http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html

And also in manifest file, set of permissions to be given

```
<uses-permission android:name=".LocationGoogleMapV2Demo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code for the google map I am doing this from the androidhive.com

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleHeaders;
import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.json.JsonHttpParser;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class GooglePlaces {

    /** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
    private static final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();

    // Google API Key
    private static final String API_KEY = "AIzaSyCRLa4LQZWNQBcjCYcIVYA45i9i8zfClqc";

    // Google Places serach url's
    private static final String PLACES_SEARCH_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?";
    private static final String PLACES_TEXT_SEARCH_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?";
    private static final String PLACES_DETAILS_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?";

    private double _latitude;
    private double _longitude;
    private double _radius;

    /**
     * Searching places
     * @param latitude - latitude of place
     * @params longitude - longitude of place
     * @param radius - radius of searchable area
     * @param types - type of place to search
     * @return list of places
     * */
    public PlacesList search(double latitude, double longitude, double radius, String types)
            throws Exception {

        this._latitude = latitude;
        this._longitude = longitude;
        this._radius = radius;

        try {

            HttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = createRequestFactory(HTTP_TRANSPORT);
            HttpRequest request = httpRequestFactory
                    .buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(PLACES_SEARCH_URL));
            request.getUrl().put("key", API_KEY);
            request.getUrl().put("location", _latitude + "," + _longitude);
            request.getUrl().put("radius", _radius); // in meters
            request.getUrl().put("sensor", "false");
            if(types != null)
                request.getUrl().put("types", types);

            PlacesList list = request.execute().parseAs(PlacesList.class);
            // Check log cat for places response status
            Log.d("Places Status", "" + list.status);
            return list;

        } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
            Log.e("Error:", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

    }

    /**
     * Searching single place full details
     * @param refrence - reference id of place
     *                 - which you will get in search api request
     * */
    public PlaceDetails getPlaceDetails(String reference) throws Exception {
        try {

            HttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = createRequestFactory(HTTP_TRANSPORT);
            HttpRequest request = httpRequestFactory
                    .buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(PLACES_DETAILS_URL));
            request.getUrl().put("key", API_KEY);
            request.getUrl().put("reference", reference);
            request.getUrl().put("sensor", "false");

            PlaceDetails place = request.execute().parseAs(PlaceDetails.class);

            return place;

        } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
            Log.e("Error in Perform Details", e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creating http request Factory
     * */
    public static HttpRequestFactory createRequestFactory(
            final HttpTransport transport) {
        return transport.createRequestFactory(new HttpRequestInitializer() {
            public void initialize(HttpRequest request) {
                GoogleHeaders headers = new GoogleHeaders();
                headers.setApplicationName("AndroidHive-Places-Test");
                request.setHeaders(headers);
                JsonHttpParser parser = new JsonHttpParser(new JacksonFactory());
                request.addParser(parser);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

And for the api key U can open androidhive.com and register to this..u  can get the tutorial about the google map